# How to fix 'An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set'

Tags: c#

My program explodes when I try to make a GET request using HttpClient.GetStringAsync.

This is the error message:

`An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.`

It is assumed that based on an IP selected by the user my program makes requests to its different variations to know which one is available.
For example:
The user selects "192.168.0.20", then my program must make a request to "192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, ..."

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

```
            try
            {
                string[] ips = cbxIps.SelectedValue.ToString().Split('.');
                string ip = ips[0] + "." + ips[1] + "." + ips[2] + ".";
                for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    var responseString = client.GetStringAsync(ip + i.ToString() + ":8080/alive");
                    if (responseString.Result == "200")
                    {
                        Servidor s = new Servidor(IPAddress.Parse(ip + i.ToString()), "Servidor " + i.ToString());
                        Servidor.Agregar(s);
                    }
                }
                Actualizar();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the HTTP scheme (http:// or https://) before the ip address when calling GetStringAsync

For instance,

```
var responseString = client.GetStringAsync("https://" + ip + i.ToString() + ":8080/alive");
```